# trying to get an index of an item in a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, indexing

I'm using python 3.3.
I want to get in index of a item in the list but no by it's number.

Now I want 'i' to equal the index of 'a'.(in this case 3.)

But if it's in a loop, 'a' will change and I want 'i' to change again to the new index of 'a.

```
mylist = [3,5,7,8,4,6,3,8,7]
a = mylist[3]
i = 'index of a'
for index in range(len(mylist)):
    a+1
    "I want i to keep changing as well but not just (i+1) 'a' might go a few directions by if's"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mylist = [3,5,7,8,4,6,3,8,7]
for index in range(len(mylist)):
    print 'number '+str(mylist[index])+' has index '+str(index)
```

Comment: i'm trying to get the index of any value in the list, doesn't matter if it's already there before. it's probably nothing to do with index at all. I just never ran into that problem before.

Comment: @dav_sap I don't understand what you mean by your goal?  Your trying to get `i=7`?  `i = mylist[mylist.index(7)];` would do it but don't know why you would want that. Can you rephrase your question to be more clear on what your looking for?

Comment: @dav_sap check my update.. If it does not help please let me know.. When you say `Now I want 'i' to equal the index of 'a'.(in this case 4.)` did you mean `3` instead of `4`?